# EasyAdmin 3: List view shows only one entity, count = 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

A Representative entity, mapped via joined inheritance to the User entity, in list view shows a count of 3 but displays only one. Representative is also in a ManyToOne relationship to the Nonprofit entity. What needs to happen to show all three Representatives?

The sequence of database queries (seen in the profiler) shows the 6th of 6 queries to return the id of the nonprofit of the representative in list view. I suspect this is strongly related to the fact that only one rep is shown.

Edit: This behavior does not occur in EA2. Only after migrating to EA3.

Edit #2: In EA2 there are 10 db queries vs only 6 in EA3. The difference is that in EA2 there are queries for the properties of nonprofits with ids of 1, 2, & 3; in EA3 there are only queries for the properties of nonprofit with id 3.

Screenshot:
[image: fuzzy photo of list view]

Representative entity (snippet):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="staff")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Representative extends User
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nonprofit", inversedBy="reps", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orgId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $nonprofit;
...
}
```

User entity (snippet):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="usertable")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"rep" = "Representative", "volunteer" = "Volunteer", "admin" = "Admin"})
 */
abstract class User implements UserInterface
{
...
}
```

Representative CRUD Controller:

```
class RepresentativeCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Representative::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, 'Edit %entity_name%')
            ->setHelp('index', 'Locking staff deactivates nonprofit and blocks staff log in. Replacing also removes current staff.')
            ->setSearchFields(['id', 'roles', 'email', 'fname', 'sname', 'confirmationToken', 'replacementStatus']);
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable('new', 'edit', 'delete');
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        $roles = ArrayField::new('roles');
        $password = TextField::new('password');
        $email = TextField::new('email');
        $fname = TextField::new('fname');
        $sname = TextField::new('sname');
        $lastLogin = DateTimeField::new('lastLogin');
        $confirmationToken = TextField::new('confirmationToken');
        $tokenExpiresAt = DateTimeField::new('tokenExpiresAt');
        $locked = BooleanField::new('locked');
        $enabled = BooleanField::new('enabled');
        $replacementStatus = TextField::new('replacementStatus');
        $initiated = DateField::new('initiated');
        $completed = DateField::new('completed');
        $nonprofit = AssociationField::new('nonprofit');
        $id = IntegerField::new('id', 'ID');
        $replace = TextareaField::new('replace')->setTemplatePath('Admin/replace_staff.html.twig');
        $fullName = TextareaField::new('fullName');
        $orgname = TextareaField::new('orgname');

        if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [$replace, $fullName, $email, $orgname];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
            return [$id, $roles, $password, $email, $fname, $sname, $lastLogin, $confirmationToken, $tokenExpiresAt, $locked, $enabled, $replacementStatus, $initiated, $completed, $nonprofit];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_NEW === $pageName) {
            return [$roles, $password, $email, $fname, $sname, $lastLogin, $confirmationToken, $tokenExpiresAt, $locked, $enabled, $replacementStatus, $initiated, $completed, $nonprofit];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName) {
            return [$roles, $password, $email, $fname, $sname, $lastLogin, $confirmationToken, $tokenExpiresAt, $locked, $enabled, $replacementStatus, $initiated, $completed, $nonprofit];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3802#issuecomment-706526321) i assume that your primary key property is private. Making it protected should solve the problem.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="usertable")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"rep" = "Representative", "volunteer" = "Volunteer", "admin" = "Admin"})
 */
abstract class User implements UserInterface
{
    protected $id;
}
```

Comment: Outstanding! Much appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem but changing the id property from private to protected did not fix the issue. Any suggestion?